# Magento Product Qty in stock but not showing in drop down

Tags: magento, stock

I have a configurable product which contains a number of simple products (each for a different size of product). Each simple product has an inventory value against it, but for some reason, one particular size, although it has an inventory value of 9, does not appear on the drop down on the front end.

All the other sizes do for the same product and I've compared them to ones appearing and can see no difference. I've cleared caches, updated indexes, etc. but nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you make sure its set to "In stock", "Enabled", Price > 0, quantity in addition to inventory?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Configurable Product and checking that all of the simple products associated with it are added.

Foot of the Product Information -> Associated Products page.

The simple product that's not showing in the front end is most probably missing from the group.

Hope this helps.